# How to find source file of .net Built in functions like WriteLine()

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to view the source code of some built in c# functions and trying to explore System.Console class etc..  I used ctrl+click by hovering over the built-in functions like ReadLine(). On using ctrl+click it redirects me to System.Console metadata page -> where I could find **only a declaration is available**

```
    // Summary:
    //     Writes the specified string value, followed by the current line terminator, to
    //     the standard output stream.
public static void WriteLine(string value);
```

In the above case, the function is only declared **but couldn't find any definition**.  So, could someone please help with this?  Is there any way to find out the source code definitions of built-in c# functions?

Comment: By using google: 

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs.html

Comment: [.NET Core is on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/Console.cs)

Comment: [.NET Core Source Browser](https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/Console.cs,748bde83a8b838d8).

Comment: Take a look [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,748bde83a8b838d8)

Answer (score 0):

If no source code are provided you can use [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy)